# Cant run HttpTrigger Azure Function from another azure function

Tags: c#, azure, http-post, azure-functions

Here is function.json snippet

```
{
  "bindings": [
    {
      "authLevel": "function",
      "name": "query",
      "type": "httpTrigger",
      "direction": "in",
      "methods": [
        "get",
        "post"
      ]
```

Here is my run.csx file:

```
public class Query{
    public double AdvanceDays{get;set;}
}
public static async Task<HttpResponseMessage> Run(Query query,entity Entity,HttpRequestMessage req, TraceWriter log, IEnumerable<dynamic> inputDocument)
{
```

Now I need to call this Http triggered function from another function. I am doing:

```
var url = "https://azurefunction...";
var content2 = new StringContent(string.Format("{{\"AdvanceDays\":7}}"));
var response = await client.PostAsync(url,content2);
```

But I get the following error:
**`No MediaTypeFormatter is available to read an object of type 'Query' from content with media type 'text/plain'.`**

How do I fix this? Please help!!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like the issue is that the request you're sending doesn't specify its content-type, and it defaults to `text/plain`. Since there's no [`Content-type header`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Content-Type), the function doesn't know which type of content you're sending. You should add a `Content-Type header` with the value `application/json`.

> The **Accept** request-header field can be used to specify certain media types which are acceptable for the response.
>
> The **Content-Type** entity-header field indicates the media type of the entity-body sent to the recipient or, in the case of the HEAD method, the media type that would have been sent had the request been a GET.

Source: [Accept header vs Content-Type Header](http://java-allandsundry.com/2012/08/accept-header-vs-content-type-header.html)

Comment: Although it's working now I am getting a very weird error. When I call Func1 from Func2, Func1 gets executed properly and returns success. But in Func1, I get the following log

Comment: `2018-07-02T13:40:00.240 [Info] Function started (Id=f68ea59d-5988-4fda-939b-4bc4195e4ad4)
2018-07-02T13:40:00.475 [Info] C# HTTP trigger function processed a request.
2018-07-02T13:41:40.524 [Error] Exception while executing function:Functions.HttpTriggerCSharp3. mscorlib: Exception has been thrown by the target of an invocation. mscorlib: One or more errors occurred. A task was canceled.
2018-07-02T13:41:40.571 [Error] Function completed (Failure, Id=f68ea59d-5988-4fda-939b-4bc4195e4ad4, Duration=100325ms)`

Comment: That probably needs a good debugging session. Please check the function, try debugging it and create a *new question* if you're not able to fix it. Are you using any external references that might act up?

Comment: So Calling Function and Called function both run smoothly individually. I am just calling the Called Function from Calling Function. The Called Func shows success in logs. Since the calling function does not do anything except calling this function, I dont get a reason why Calling function would show this error? Both are **Timer Triggered Azure Functions** btw. Is it because Calling Function is **`async`**?
`public static async Task<HttpResponseMessage> Run(HttpRequestMessage req, TraceWriter log)`

Comment: Check to see what data is coming in, and if it's in the expected format. I can image this: `string.Format("{{\"AdvanceDays\":7}}")` gives a different result then you're expecting.